# Multiple MaxRequestsPerChild Settings

Tags: django, apache, apache2, mod-wsgi

I've been developing a Django application with some friends. We're finally about to release our app into the wild. This means we need to get rid of our "MaxRequestsPerChild 1" setting in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf for performance.

However, we still want to have this setting turned on for our development subdomains. Is it possible to have a different MaxRequestsPerChild setting for individual virtual hosts? Or does the directive have to be set globally?

Comment: this setting means the apache fork is killed after each request. Can you explain us why you think you need it in dev?

Comment: The use of "MaxRequestsPerChild 1" is suggested in the django help https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modpython/ - see section "Running a development server with mod_python"

Answer (score 1):

If you were using MaxRequestsPerChild it means you were running in embedded mode which likely you should never have been in the first place.

You should use daemon mode instead, especially when developing as you can better control reloading of processes when code changes. See:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

Simple example of setting up daemon mode can be found at:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide#Delegation_To_Daemon_Process